# How to use unique validation in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have comments table:

[image]

My Comment controller where its taking values from form and validating it and storing it in database.

```
public function store(Request $request, $product_id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'email'=> 'required|email|unique:comments,product_id',
            'comment' => 'required',
            'rating' => 'required|integer'
            ));
        $product = Product::find($product_id);
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->name = $request->name;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->rating = $request->rating;
        $comment->product()->associate($product);

        $comment->save();
        Session::flash('success','Comment was added');
        return redirect()->route('product.show',[$product->id]);
    }
```

**I am trying to validate such that only unique email id is allowed to comment on every product_id that is if user has already commented on product_id 1 then the same user is not allowed to comment again on that id.**

I tried

```
'email'=> 'required|email|unique:comments,product_id'
```

But as u can see about same email id data was entered for same product_id.

A user can comment on n number of product_id page but cannot comment again once he has commented on that id.

**Is there a way to validate if email data has been entered in database for particular product_id then the same email is not allowed to submit the form.**

[image]

If different product_id then email can enter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Write this in your console

```
php artisan make:provider ValidationServiceProvider
```

Then replace your `App\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider` with

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Validator;
use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot() {
    Validator::extend('unique_email_comment', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      return !Comment::where('email', $value)->where('product_id', $parameters[0])->exists();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Register the service provider.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register() {
    //
  }
}
```

**Note :-** Please ensure the Model `App\Comment` is replaced with the namespace of the modal you use for your comments system.

Now add it to **providers** in `config/app.php` like

```
App\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
```

Now, you can validate the existence of the row by:

```
'email' => 'unique_email_comment:' . $productId;

// or
// 'email' => 'unique_email_comment:' . request()->get('product_id');
```

You can also add a custom message like this

```
return [
  'email.unique_email_comment' => 'A comment has already been made for this product with the email provided';
]
```

**Please note that I haven't tested the code out but this should work if all the data is passed correctly and all namespaces are correctly used.**

Comment: @Phoenix Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: where do I add custom message

Comment: Simply make a custom `$messages = [....]` and add it as a third parameter to `Validator::make()` like `Validator::make($inputs, $rules, $messages)`

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `unique` rule works. For your task you need to create custom validation rule and check manually if user with this email had already commented this product.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: can you please create a sample rule according to problem above as I can't figure out after reading documentation as I am not so experienced with laravel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `unique_with` custom validation. May be this package with full fill your requirement. You can check and get example [here](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can use **multiple columns** for the unique rule. You have to manually check that by firing a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validation rule `unique`. [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique)

`use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

```
$this->validate($request, array(
     'name' => 'required',
     'email'=> ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('comments', 'email')->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('product_id', $product_id);
               })],
     ...
));
```

Hope this will help you