# Laravel 5 How to validate a unique customer name under each Activity when save

Tags: laravel-5.3

I had three model: Activity Model, Customer Model and Customeritem Model

How to do the validation checking in store function whereby the customer name should be UNIQUE in each Activity?

Below is each migration files

Activity Model

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('activityName');
        $table->string('activityCode');
        $table->string('activityVenue');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Customer Model

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('activities_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->foreign('activities_id')->references('id')->on('activities')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text('remark')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Customeritem Model

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customeritems', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('customers_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->foreign('customers_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('customerName');
        $table->integer('customerAge')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Controller for Store new entry

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'customerName' => 'required|distinct',         
    );
    $messages = array(
        'customerName.required'=>'Customer Name is required',
        'customerName.distinct'=>'Customer Name has a duplicate value.',
    );
```

Here how to do validation for unique customerName for each activity?

Comment: what's the entry you're storing? Customer? Activity? CustomerItem? we need a brief about what's the logic behind this. what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Hi @M.Elwan the entry i want to store is Customeritem. Each customer name in Customeritem must be unique in each activity. so how should i validate in store function? $rules = array(
        'customerName' => 'required|distinct|unique:???',         
    );

Comment: my logic is almost the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054301/how-to-use-unique-validation-in-laravel but i don't know how to apply it in my code

Comment: hmm, @jovenDev, your link is pretty much a straight forward answer. you can try to make the custom validator class and modify the `public function boot() {...}` codes to suit your need.

Comment: Hi but i don't know how to modify it in public function boot() {...}, especially it involved multiple related table