# Laravel 5 How to get the Total number of customers who have only two orders

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

i want to display the total number of customers who have only two orders in my view blade. Below are my Table, Model, and the Data

Customer Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('customerName');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Customer Model

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'customers_id');
}
```

Order Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('customers_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('customers_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->date('orderDate');
        $table->float('orderDetails');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Order Model

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'customers_id');
}
```

[image]

From the data above some customers have two order. So i need to know how to get the total customers who have two orders.

Comment: well.. have scoured the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)..? i saw the example have `$posts = Post::has('comments', '>=', 3)->get();`, basically this checks whether `Post`'s have `Comments`.

Comment: thanks, i had tried it, it works! Mind to assist me in this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341798/laravel-5-how-to-validate-a-unique-customer-name-under-each-activity-when-save